# Hibernate - different persistence approaches

Tags: java, hibernate

Are there any differences, pros/cons of using any of the hibernate persistence mechanisms

- Native API & hbm.xml files
- Annotations
- Java Persistence API (JPA)
- Envers

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing your metaphors here

- Native API & hbm.xml are used by Hibernate to read and write to a database. They convert objects to a relational tables
- Annotations is a way of specifying in a class the various relationships between objects/table. This can be used instead of hbm.xml
- JPA is a framework for implementing O-R and the bits around it. You can use JPA with Hibernate.
- Envers I dont know much about but I belive is an auditing module within Hibernate

I would recommend keeping things as generic as possible so that if Hibernate does not meet your needs to you can use EclipseLink or something else. If you tie yourself down to hibernate then it will be very hard to move if you have problems (saying that I used hibernate and never had reasons to move.... yet ;) )

I would recommend looking up more details on each of these and them coming back with specific questions

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Vs JPA Semantics:
We use JPA semantics throughout our projects which is similar to interface based implementation where JPA specification is like interface definition and Hibernate is the provider that implements the specification.

Annotations Vs hbm.xml:
We decided to use annotations instead of specifying the entity definition in XML files to make correlation between domain object and database objects easier and well connected.